# Creating DropDownLists from the detail for a grouped ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a new model from several tables in a MVC Entity Framework model.

```
namespace Prototype_07.Models
{
    public class MyQuestionModel
    {
        public Questionaire Questionaire { get; set; }
        public QuestionaireSection QuestionaireSection { get; set; }
        public Section Section { get; set; }
        public SectionQuestion SectionQuestion { get; set; }
        public Question Question { get; set; }
        public QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }
        public QuestionAnswerListCode QuestionAnswerListCode { get; set; }
        public AnswerListCode AnswerListCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller code is:

public class MyQuestionController : Controller
{
    private PrototypeEntities db = new PrototypeEntities();

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = from qa in db.Questionaires
                    join qas in db.QuestionaireSections on qa.QuestionaireKey equals qas.QuestionaireKey
                    join s in db.Sections on qas.SectionKey equals s.SectionKey
                    join sq in db.SectionQuestions on s.SectionKey equals sq.SectionKey
                    join q in db.Questions on sq.QuestionKey equals q.QuestionKey
                    join qtc in db.QuestionTypes on q.QuestionTypeKey equals qtc.QuestionTypeKey
                    join qddl in db.QuestionAnswerListCodes on q.QuestionKey equals qddl.QuestionKey
                    join ddl in db.AnswerListCodes on qddl.AnswerListCodeKey equals ddl.AnswerListCodeKey
                    where qa.QuestionaireName.Equals("TAD")
                    select new MyQuestionModel
                    {
                        Questionaire = qa,
                        QuestionaireSection = qas,
                        Section = s,
                        SectionQuestion = sq,
                        Question = q,
                        QuestionType = qtc,
                        QuestionAnswerListCode = qddl,
                        AnswerListCode = ddl
                    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

My looking to created a view that looks like this [Image](http://3pc.com/images/image.jpg)

In my view I'm stuck on how to group the questions and populate the dropdown lists.  What is the MVC way to do this?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.First().Questionaire.QuestionaireName)</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.QuestionaireSection.DefaultSequence).OrderBy(x => x.SectionQuestion.DefaultSequence).OrderBy(x => x.QuestionAnswerListCode.DefaultSequence)) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Section.SectionName))
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question.Question1)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DropDownListFor(??????)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.QuestionAnswerListCode.AnswerList, @Model.AnswerListCode)
```

I think if you showed the properties of the tables that would help too.

Comment: The dropdown should contain answers not questions.  Each question has a different set of possible answers in the dropdown.  AnswerListCode contains all answers, QuestionAnswerListCode connects questions to possible answers.